# Time machine freezes mac?

Tags: macos, itunes, time-machine, performance

I had just installed new SSD on main bay and move HDD instead of SuperDrive on my 2011 MBP. All works perfectly but Time Machine. It freezes entire mac when I trying open `Options` on `Time machine` preferences pane. I already removed old time machine config but its doesnt help me..

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**UPD:** also it freezes on iTunes launch... Maybe its cuz of symlinks beetween HDD and SSD? I will try and reply soon.

**UPD2:** no it is not a symbolic links.

Comment: Run Disk Utility and do a full disk scan.  You might have bad sectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So its solved by **wait until freeze over** - its about an 20 mins. I do not know what exactly it was but now its works as should.
If you have the same issue try to wait about an hour - maybe, it will helps you too.